# Compare types and process functions depending on type of input F#

Tags: f#

I have a list of rooms that each contain an object that is either a weapon, bomb or monster, is there a way I can check which type is contained, and then call on different functions depending on this? Below is a previous attempt to do so.

```
let ritemprocess (a:Room) = 
    match a.item.GetType with
    | Bomb -> procBomb(a.item)
```

Here I am looking at the item of a room, and if it is a bomb I call the process bomb function, which requires type bomb as an input to work, however the error I get is that a.item is type object not type Bomb.

Type room is like so:

```
    type Room = {
    id:int;
    item:obj;
    n:int;
    e:int;
    s:int;
    w:int;
    complete:bool;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# is statically typed; when your Room type says item is of type `obj`, it's precisely that, you can't use it in a context that would require something that is *not* an `obj`. There is a way of circumventing it with run-time type casting:

```
let ritemprocess (a:Room) = 
    match a.item with
    | :? Bomb as bomb -> procBomb bomb
    ...
```

but usually it would be considered a code smell when it happens as part of your domain model.

A typical approach would be to have a discriminated union to model your item type:

```
type Item =
    | Weapon of Weapon
    | Bomb of Bomb
    | Monster of Monster

type Room = {
    id:int;
    item:Item;
    n:int;
    e:int;
    s:int;
    w:int;
    complete:bool;
}
```

assuming `Weapon/Bomb/Monster` are types the already exist in your code. Then you just match on the Item type cases:

```
let ritemprocess (a:Room) = 
    match a.item with
    | Bomb bomb -> procBomb bomb
    ...
```